# Multiple programmers on same local git repository all using Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, visual-studio-2019

My team and I have a group of projects we're working on, using the same local git repository on a network location. Up to now this has worked well for us, with changes one developer making being immediately reflected to someone else working on the same project with a popup indicating that a change has been made. Recently, a new developer arrived and since then we've been running into cases in which this isn't working correctly and one developer could make changes, not get any indication of changes, save his work and overwrite changes made by someone else.

Before I start, **I know that working in this configuration is not recommended**. I know that ideally, every developer should have his own local git repository to work on so that one person's changes cannot affect someone elses. Furthermore, let's assume, for arguments sake, that I have good reason to work in this configuration (so please, no comments about "just stop using this configuration because it's wrong"). **Under that assumption**, does anyone know why this could occur? Why should visual studio stop updating me when changes are made to the project I'm working on (under a local git repository) from outside my environment?

Couple of comments:

- We all work with vs pro 2017
- The new developer started working with vs pro 2019 and switched to 2017
- some of us used resharper, but stopped using it due to various bugs

Comment: Under your assumption: Could be a file locking issue. The more parallel users, the higher the chance each of these is trying to read and change the same files. Any info in the Git Output Window?

Comment: It will probably be less of an issue when you'd rely solely on the commanline to execute commands, Visual Studio will continuously scan for changes which causes each instance of Visual Studio to open and close files.

Comment: Ok.... I won't tell you that _you are doing it wrong_ and that _you should stop doing it_... look. Now, for real, you should start working _properly_ because you are just working in a fashion where a couple of developers _might_ get away with.... but a team of develppers will just start facing issue after issue because you are stepping on each other's toes... it is to be expected, no solution for this... other than.... guess what.

Comment: I explicitly stated that I realize the problems with this configuration to stave off such comments. I don't want to get into details because this is a rather extended discussion in and of itself, but suffice it to say that I have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit - it was resharper. We uninstalled it and the problem went away. I'd be glad for comments if anyone knows or suspects why resharper could cause this problem.